# Excel VBA - Dynamic setting of Calculated Item in Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table which uses calculated items . My Input for the calculated item changes dynamically. I have been asking the User to Input the formula using InputBox Method. But now, I want to set it to dynamic but I couldn't make them work. Here goes my data,

```
   Category Checks
    18-20   Yes
    18-20   Yes
    16-18   Yes
    16-18   Yes
    20-24   Yes
    24-30   Yes
    30-35   Yes
    35-40   Yes
    14-16   Yes
```

And this is the Pivot table output that I am looking for ,

```
    Column Labels       
                Less than 20    More than 20    Grand Total
Count of Checks 5              4                9
```

Less than 20 and More than 20 are calculated items. Initially I was hardcoding the formula like this -

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").CalculatedItems. _
        Add "Less than 20", "='16-18' +'18-20'", True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").CalculatedItems. _
        Add "More than 20", "='20-24' +'24-30' +'30-35' +'35-40'", True
```

There were no problems when all these categories ( '16-18', '18-20' etc.,) are present. But it is not present in some of the sheets.

Then I asked the User to Input the Formula by setting a String Variable. But now, I want it to be more dynamic and the formula to happen automatically. Kindly help me with this. I tried a lot FOR 2 days, but I couldn't get the logic going.

I am able to get the Unique values inside the column category at the moment. Now, How do I set it inside the formula

```
colmz = WorksheetFunction.Match("Category", Sheets(Ssheet1").Rows(1), 0)
Nrowz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colmz).End(xlUp).Row
B = GetColumnName(colmz)

    For i = 2 To Nrowz
        CellVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(B & i).Value
        On Error Resume Next
        Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    For Each itm In Col
        Debug.Print itm
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good option would be to use the Group functionality in the Pivot Table. You just select the columns that you want to group --> right click -> select Group from the context menu.

[image]

The pivot will then do the grouping for you so it looks like the below.

[image]

And then your user can choose to click on the + button to drill down and see the ungrouped items if they want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But that still doesn't solve the problem if I don't have the Category(14-16) in some of the worksheets. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you creating multiple pivot tables on top of multiple worksheets?

Comment: Its more like, I write one piece of code and that will be used for different worksheets to produce the report. One Pivot Table for one worksheet but I want to use the same code for the next week data as well which may not have some of these categories.

Comment: If you base the pivot table and groupings on a worksheet that contains all of the catregories at the start then it won't matter if some categories are missing in future. In my example if I deleted the 14-16 row from the worksheet and refresh the pivot table then it still works fine. Are you just copying and pasting new data into the worksheet each week?

Comment: Not copying and pasting it. The process runs like - Removes everything from the worksheet to scratch and then copies the data for the next week.

Comment: ok. Then the solution I suggested should work fine. Let me know if not. Also you said you are not copying and pasting but the process you describe sounds exactly that e.g. you remove everything and then copy and paste in the next weeks data to the worksheet.

Comment: I will try and get back to you sir. It removes everything sir - even the pivot table in the workbook that's where the problem starts I think over here.

Comment: No Sir. Suppose lets consider this, I remove all the elements that belong to Group2 and run the report by refreshing the Pivot table. It gives blank in the Pivot table inspite of 0 which I am looking for. And even the name of the Group2 is blank

Comment: I don't know any way around that. A pivot table is a summary of the underlying data. If you don't have any data that falls into the Group then it won't display the group.

Comment: Ok Sir ! Thanks for your suggestions. I will keep this question for a day. If I couldn't come-up with an answer I will close it. Thanks @n4nite

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Pivot Table named "PivotTable5" in the active sheet, that may or may not have the items in your list in the field called "Category", you can use some dynamic string variables for your calculated item.  Here's some quick VBA I threw together that would solve this specific problem.

```
Sub Macro1()
    'DECLARE VARIABLES
        Dim STRING_ITEMS As String
        Dim STRING_LESS_THAN20 As String
        Dim STRING_MORE_THAN20 As String
    
        Dim PT_ITEM As PivotItem
    
    'LOOP THROUGH PIVOT ITEMS TO BUILD A HELPER STRING OF ALL ITEMS THAT END UP SHOWING UP IN THE PIVOT TABLE.
        STRING_ITEMS = ""
        For Each PT_ITEM In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").PivotItems
            Select Case PT_ITEM.Name
                'MAKE SURE TO MAKE A CASE BUCKET FOR ALL UNIQUE POSSIBLE CATEGORIES
                    Case Is = "14-16"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '14-16'"
                    Case Is = "16-18"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '16-18'"
                    Case Is = "18-20"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '18-20'"
                    Case Is = "20-24"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '20-24'"
                    Case Is = "24-30"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '24-30'"
                    Case Is = "30-35"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '30-35'"
                    Case Is = "35-40"
                        STRING_ITEMS = STRING_ITEMS & ", '35-40'"
            End Select
        Next PT_ITEM
    'REMOVE THE "," AT THE FRONT OF THE STRING
        If Left(STRING_ITEMS, 1) = "," Then
            STRING_ITEMS = Right(STRING_ITEMS, Len(STRING_ITEMS) - 1)
        End If
    'WE'RE LEFT WITH A DYNAMIC STRING INCLUDING ONLY THE ITEMS THAT SHOW UP IN THE PIVOT TABLE IN THIS FORMAT:  '14-16','20-24','30-35'
    
    
    'NOW BUILD THE NEXT HELPER STRING - LESS THAN 20
        STRING_LESS_THAN20 = ""
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'14-16'") > 0 Then
            STRING_LESS_THAN20 = STRING_LESS_THAN20 & ", '14-16'"
        End If
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'16-18'") > 0 Then
            STRING_LESS_THAN20 = STRING_LESS_THAN20 & ", '16-18'"
        End If
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'18-20'") > 0 Then
            STRING_LESS_THAN20 = STRING_LESS_THAN20 & ", '18-20'"
        End If
    'REMOVE "," IN FRONT
        If Left(STRING_LESS_THAN20, 1) = "," Then
            STRING_LESS_THAN20 = Right(STRING_LESS_THAN20, Len(STRING_LESS_THAN20) - 1)
        End If
        
        
    'NOW BUILD THE NEXT HELPER STRING - MORE THAN 20
        STRING_MORE_THAN20 = ""
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'20-24'") > 0 Then
            STRING_MORE_THAN20 = STRING_MORE_THAN20 & ", '20-24'"
        End If
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'24-30'") > 0 Then
            STRING_MORE_THAN20 = STRING_MORE_THAN20 & ", '24-30'"
        End If
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'30-35'") > 0 Then
            STRING_MORE_THAN20 = STRING_MORE_THAN20 & ", '30-35'"
        End If
        If InStr(1, STRING_ITEMS, "'35-40'") > 0 Then
            STRING_MORE_THAN20 = STRING_MORE_THAN20 & ", '35-40'"
        End If
    'REMOVE "," IN FRONT
        If Left(STRING_MORE_THAN20, 1) = "," Then
            STRING_MORE_THAN20 = Right(STRING_MORE_THAN20, Len(STRING_MORE_THAN20) - 1)
        End If
        
        
    'YOU NOW HAVE 3 CLEAN STRINGS THAT ARE SET UP FOR A NICE "SUM" CALCULATED ITEM
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").CalculatedItems.Add "LESS THAN 20", _
        "=SUM(" & STRING_LESS_THAN20 & ")", True
        
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").CalculatedItems.Add "MORE THAN 20", _
        "=SUM(" & STRING_MORE_THAN20 & ")", True
        
    'IF YOU ONLY WANT THESE 2 CALCULATED ITEMS TO DISPLAY, YOU CAN HIDE THE OTHER ITEMS
        For Each PT_ITEM In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category").PivotItems
            Select Case PT_ITEM.Name
                Case Is = "LESS THAN 20"
                Case Is = "MORE THAN 20"
                Case Else
                    PT_ITEM.Visible = False
            End Select
        Next PT_ITEM
End Sub
```